# I have no access to images from code (R.drawable ...)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, png

I'm working on an Android game with Eclipse, suddenly appears lots of errors in the code. Eclipse now don't recognize R.drawable resources .... 
Console shows the following warning: 
libpng warning: Ignoring gAMA chunk with gamma=0

What can I do to continue as it was?

Comment: The generated R.java has the images correctly in the code

Comment: Did you try restarting Eclipse?

Comment: The message is just a warning, you can ignore it. Are you getting any other actual errors? I assume you mean errors in the log, not errors in the code.

Comment: Yes, i tried restarting Eclipse and the the computer... same problem.

Comment: The message is a warning, but I can't ignore it cause the code can't access now to the images

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted, i spent over 30 minutes trying to figure that out and every solution i found suggested to refresh the project, clean... but this was actually my problem! Thanks @Fischer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution. seems there was an error in the import of the R file (resources file). 
I replaced 
    import android.R
for 
    import package.name.R

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm definetly not the most advanced guy out here but I have lost my R.java file more than a couple of times. You lose the whole thing whenever there is one thing that should be added but has an error. So almost all of those errors that you are seeing are secondary errors. Did you add an image or some other type of resource that you can think of when you lost your r.java?

Comment: This happened after adding an png image to drawable directory. The code didn't recognize the new image, and i tried with the clean tool of Eclipse. After it, i have no access to any image

Comment: Ya once that r.java file is gone it makes it really tough to figure out the problem because of all the errors everywhere. I would try to dissasociate your code completely from that bad image as in the reference to it in your code. Good luck and I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Cleaning and Building the project?  Go to Project > Clean and clean your project.  Then try running it again.  Most of the time when I see problems with my R.java a clean and build will fix it.

If that doesn't help, can you paste your code or a sampling of it?

Comment: int heads[] = { R.drawable.h1, R.drawable.h2, R.drawable.h3 };

Comment: what about the resources in you project folders... are there any file types in there that android rejects?  e.g. unsupported audio types, images types, etc.